# Applying the Myhill-Nerode Theorem

Tags: regular-language

Consider the language $$L=\{x y^{(n)} z y^{(n)} w: x,z,w \in \Sigma^*, y \in \Sigma, z\text{ does not contain }y, n \geq 0 \}.$$
To show that the language is not regular using the Myhill-Nerode Theorem, I have to show that there are infinite number of equivalence classes, right? But how can I find these equivalence classes?

Comment: Are you sure this representation of the language correct?  It seems to me that $L = \Sigma^*$.  (For any string $u$ either some symbol $\mathtt{x}$ doesn't appear at least twice in which case you can take $u = x \mathtt{x}^0 z \mathtt{x}^0 w$ with no $\mathtt{x}$s in $z$, or if some symbol $\mathtt{x}$ appears twice you can express $u$ as $x \mathtt{x}^1 z \mathtt{x}^1 w$ where these represent consecutive occurrences of $\mathtt{x}$ in $u$.) Perhaps some condition on $L$ is missing?  (No occurrences of $y$ in any of $x,z,w$?)

Comment: This language is given from the exercise I am looking at.Do you think it is a misprint ? So,can we not apply the Myhill-Nerode Theorem?

Comment: My outline above seems to show that $L = \Sigma^*$, which is clearly regular.  (Of course, you _could_ use Myhill-Nerode to show that $\Sigma^*$ is regular, though that seems pretty pointless.)

Comment: Could you tell me some of the equivalence classes of the language that is given??Are some of them: $xzw,xyzyw,xyyzyyw$ ?Or am I wrong?

Comment: If my outline is correct and $L = \Sigma^*$, then there is only one equivalence class: that corresponding to the empty string $\varepsilon$. (Note that $xyzyw$ and $xyyzyyw$ would be equivalent since for any $u$ we will have $xyzywu$ and $xyyzyywu$ in $L$.)

Comment: yes, take $z=w=\epsilon$ and $n=0$ and you just have $x\in\Sigma^*$. I agree with @ArthurFischer.

Comment: I tend to over-complicate things.  Your outline is ***much better***, @Xoff.

Comment: @ArthurFischer,@Xoff could you explain me further why the only equivalence class is the empty string?I haven't understood it...

Comment: @evinda: Since every string is in $L$, then given any two strings $u , v \in \Sigma^*$ and any string $w \in \Sigma^*$ the biconditional $uw \in L \iff vw \in L$ is true, which implies that $u$ and $v$ are equivalent with respect to the "there is no  distinguishing extension" relation.  That is, all strings are equivalent with respect to this relation, or, there is only one equivalence class (represented by _any_ string, in particular, by $\varepsilon$).

Comment: @evinda: My guess is that it was intended to require that none of $x,z$, and $w$ contain $y$. Then you really do get one equivalence class for each $n\ge 0$.